# Handling self signed certificates with NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection

I want to allow a self-signed certificate with an NSURLConnection, provided that the host is in a trusted list.

I see a lot of folks doing something like this:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    if ([protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if (allowSelfSignedCertForThisHost) {
            NSLog(@"Allowing self signed!");
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host]) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

However, I'm wondering why you would invoke `useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge` but also `continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge` after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that certificate on device with `iPhone Configuration Utility` or `Apple Configurator`.

Comment: That's not feasible - it is sent by the host that I'm connecting to.

Comment: @Will, so download it and install. You don't need private key from it. Just certificate will be enough.

Comment: Would there be any code change to recognize this custom certificate? This seems simpler and more secure.

Comment: Once the custom certificate is installed, is there anything that needs to be done programmatically to recognize this certificate?

Comment: @Will, nothing. If you open yours link in Safari, it also will show that certificate is trusted.